# Growing local development environment issues

Tags: devops, development-environment

Where I work we've been adding microservices for different purposes and the local development environment is becoming difficult to setup. Services have too many environment variables to configure and usually there's not enough memory avaiable to run them.

We plan to fix these issues. I understand it's a matter of architecture and DevOps mostly. One way we've thought of is to create a proper service registry that allows easier setup and opens the door to, for example, have some services running locally and others in the cloud. All wired together with the service registry.

Another option could be to stub some of the dependencies with something like https://wiremock.org/ but it seems too limited and difficult (?).

I wanted to ask, what other strategies are there to manage growing development environments?

Comment: This is a great question and one I have been struggling with for sometime. 

Our preprod and prod environments are scaling Kubernetes clusters. I've been leaning toward having local development environments run a k8s node, which cluster with k8s running in the cloud. The developer would deploy their WIP service(s) locally, which then have access to the rest of the microservices running in the cloud. Essentially every developer would have access to their own cloud infrastructure running the full ecosystem of microservices. 

It would be great to know how companies like Netflix handle this.